# Why does Emacs allow division by zero?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was recently surprised to find that Emacs allows division by zero:

```
(/ 1.0 0)
=> 1.0e+INF
```

This only works with floats, integers raise the expected error:

```
(/ 1 0)
=> Arithmetic error
```

I've tried searching for this but can find nothing useful.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: This is the standard C behavior. It's totally standard and logical: divide by inf - get your zero back.

Comment: While we're used to the assertion "You can't divide by 0", it is actually not true, so this behavior is actually more correct than others

Comment: Infinity is not a number, so this is still correct. However, there is more to it. All computer arithmetic are modular, as in all operations are actually not just plus or minus, they are `plus modulo 2^32` or some such. So, in the context of double precision floats, the division by zero is defined, because it has special values which make it work. You can think of these special values being similar to square root of one in complex numbers in the sense that they are needed to make some larger set of theorems work.

Comment: I mentioned modulo here because infinities and nan are outside the range you can reach through doing regular math. They are "extending" the language of numbers allowing for new entities. If we could do the same in everyday math (similar to how we introduced `i` in complex numbers), we could have division by zero resulting in some `z` number, which is just not a real number, or not a complex number, or not even a transcendental irrational and neither a surreal number! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual: "Emacs uses the IEEE floating point standard, which is supported by all modern computers".

Here's a good explanation for why IEEE floating point standard works the way it does:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#919